# Run a celery worker in the background

Tags: background, celery

I am running a celery worker like this:

```
celery worker --app=portalmq --logfile=/tmp/portalmq.log --loglevel=INFO -E --pidfile=/tmp/portalmq.pid
```

Now I want to run this worker in the background. I have tried several things, including:

```
nohup celery worker --app=portalmq --logfile=/tmp/portal_mq.log --loglevel=INFO -E --pidfile=/tmp/portal_mq.pid >> /tmp/portal_mq.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

But it is not working. I have checked the celery documentation, and I found this:

- [Running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html)
- [Running the celery worker server](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#running-the-celery-worker-server)

Specially this comment is relevant:

```
In production you will want to run the worker in the background as a daemon.
To do this you need to use the tools provided by your platform, or something
like supervisord (see Running the worker as a daemon for more information).
```

This is too much overhead just to run a process in the background. I would need to install supervisord in my servers, and get familiar with it. No go at the moment. Is there a *simple* way of running a celery worker in the backrground?

Comment: do you need something more than this?
celery worker --app=portalmq --logfile=/tmp/portalmq.log --loglevel=INFO -E --pidfile=/tmp/portalmq.pid &

Comment: As I said, that does not work. The worker just stops after initializing.

Comment: & works for me without nohup. btw you can also run the worker in a detached screen. I still think that you can configure supervisor in less time (and get a nice deployment for celery)

Comment: You are correct, without nohup it is working. I do not know what went wrong before, but I had already tried that.

Answer (score 31):

supervisor is really simple and requires really little work to get it setup up, same applies for to celery in combination with supervisor.

It should not take more than 10 minutes to setup it up :)

1. install supervisor with apt-get
2. create /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf config file
3. paste somethis in the celery.conf file

   ```
   [program:celery]
   directory = /my_project/
   command = /usr/bin/python manage.py celery worker
   ```
4. plus (if you need) some optional and useful stuff (with dummy
   values)

   ```
   user = celery_user
   group = celery_group
   stdout_logfile = /var/log/celeryd.log
   stderr_logfile = /var/log/celeryd.err
   autostart = true
   environment=PATH="/some/path/",FOO="bar"
   ```
5. restart supervisor (or do supervisorctl reread; supervisorctl add
   celery)

after that you get the nice ctl commands to manage the celery process:

```
supervisorctl start/restart/stop celery

supervisorctl tail [-f] celery [stderr]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that as soon as possible.

Comment: @Tommaso What do we suppose to write in "directory = /my_project/"?

Comment: @simer the path of your Django project (the command expects to have manage.py in the path)

Answer (score 27):

```
celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info --detach
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any way to restart celery.

Comment: Restarting celery in this case requires you to do "ps aux | grep celery" in the command prompt and finding its PID, then kill it with "kill -9 <PID>"

Answer (score 5):

For me this one worked, I was using celery with django

```
celery -A proj_name worker -l INFO --detach
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem as a lazy solution is to use `&` at the end of the command. 
For example

```
celery worker -A <app>.celery --loglevel=info &
```

Comment: Not the best way, see other answers here, but still works as advertised, so I'll up vote it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below command when executed in terminal will start celery as a background process.

```
celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info --detach
```

Incase you want stop it then `ps aux | grep celery` as mentioned @Kaiss B. in another answer's comment & `kill -9 <process id>` to kill the process.

But first of all you need to install the celery for

```
apt install python-celery-common.
```

Some of the guys might be wondering why the other answers which are upvoted but not working in there system is because celery changed the command syntax from

`celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info --detach`

to

`celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info --detach`

Hope that helps.