# Trouble installing supervisord with celery

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, celery, supervisord

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I am following http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ along with the docs. I've also looked at [Run a celery worker in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814691/run-a-celery-worker-in-the-background). and http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/

In /etc/supervisor/conf.d/tp-celery.conf I have:

```
[program:tp-celery]
command=/home/ubuntu/projects/tp celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/ubuntu/projects/tp
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
```

Now following directions I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ sudo supervisorctl reread
tp-celery: available
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ sudo supervisorctl update
tp-celery: added process group
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ sudo supervisorctl status tp-celery
tp-celery                        FATAL      command at '/home/ubuntu/projects/tp' is a directory
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: once you have specified the directory element for the program object in the supervisor.conf file you dont need to specifically have the directory in the command, just try `command=celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO`

Comment: try `command=celery --app=tp.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO`, others without change

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for looking at this. I ended up following the example in http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/ because I'm working in a virtualenv, so my command looks like "command=/home/thomas/virtualenvs/yourvenv/bin/celery worker --app=myapp -l info "