# Celery worker stops when console is closed

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to run Celery in development environment, on a cloud server. I am connecting to the machine using remote SSH, and starting Celery worker with the following comand:

```sh
celery -A myapp worker -l info -f logs/celery.log
```

Everything works fine at this point, but the worker stops a few seconds after the console window is closed (ssh connection closed). How do I keep the worker running, as having an opened SSH connection permanently is not an option?

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('uiforms')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py

```py
import requests
from celery import shared_task
import json 


def auth():
    headers = {"someheaders"}
    data = {
        "somedata"
    }
    r = requests.post("url",
                      data=data,
                      headers=headers)

    return r.json()['access_token']


@shared_task
def add_queue_item(acces_token=None, content=None):
    acces_token = auth()
    headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {acces_token}",
            }
    data = json.dumps(content)
    r = requests.post("url", data=data, headers=headers)
```

cellery logs:

```
[2020-11-20 08:55:13,548: INFO/MainProcess] celery@localhost ready.
[2020-11-20 08:55:13,549: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: dlaforms.tasks.add_queue_item[517d8785-d08c-48a3-9475-b1c728daf66d]
[2020-11-20 08:55:13,550: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: dlaforms.tasks.add_queue_item[3cdc3b8e-dbea-4f69-bb3a-d87668fb7804]
[2020-11-20 08:55:14,181: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task dlaforms.tasks.add_queue_item[517d8785-d08c-48a3-9475-b1c728daf66d] succeeded in 0.5300460010184906s: None
[2020-11-20 08:55:14,702: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task dlaforms.tasks.add_queue_item[3cdc3b8e-dbea-4f69-bb3a-d87668fb7804] succeeded in 0.5188984139822423s: None
```

rabbitmq logs:

```
2020-11-20 08:42:34.239 [info] <0.16979.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.16979.4> (127.0.0.1:42646 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2020-11-20 08:42:34.243 [info] <0.16979.4> connection <0.16979.4> (127.0.0.1:42646 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2020-11-20 08:55:12.474 [info] <0.17790.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.17790.4> (127.0.0.1:42664 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2020-11-20 08:55:12.479 [info] <0.17790.4> connection <0.17790.4> (127.0.0.1:42664 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2020-11-20 08:55:12.492 [info] <0.17797.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.17797.4> (127.0.0.1:42666 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2020-11-20 08:55:12.495 [info] <0.17797.4> connection <0.17797.4> (127.0.0.1:42666 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2020-11-20 08:55:12.514 [info] <0.17811.4> accepting AMQP connection <0.17811.4> (127.0.0.1:42668 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2020-11-20 08:55:12.516 [info] <0.17811.4> connection <0.17811.4> (127.0.0.1:42668 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2020-11-20 08:58:10.277 [warning] <0.17811.4> closing AMQP connection <0.17811.4> (127.0.0.1:42668 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2020-11-20 08:58:10.279 [warning] <0.17797.4> closing AMQP connection <0.17797.4> (127.0.0.1:42666 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
2020-11-20 08:58:10.279 [warning] <0.17790.4> closing AMQP connection <0.17790.4> (127.0.0.1:42664 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814691/run-a-celery-worker-in-the-background

Comment: This is a normal behavior in Linux. To keep your process running you could run it in a screen or tmux session, that will remain active after you close the ssh connection. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux

Comment: @Md.NahidurRahman it did help, thanks.