Running a Celery server and Django server individually on the same AWS EC2 instance?
I can successfully run a django server on my EC2 instance with Ubuntu on AWS, as well as the celery server. However, unlike in my Visual Studio Code editor where I can create multiple terminals and have each one run a different server without any issue, I can't seem to do it for my EC2 instance in AWS. I tried making different tabs connecting the same instance, and while one managed to connect to the Django server, when trying to make the other one connect to the Celery server, it all just freezes.

This is the Django server running.

This is the Celery server running on the same instance but i had to close the Django server just for it to be able to run.
Basically, I ust want to run both at the same time on the same EC2 instance, if it's possible.
I have read somewhere that using this code ssh -i your_key.pem ubuntu@your_ec2_public_ip could help but i'd have to launch another instance with a paired key. I wanted to make sure if this actually helps or if there another way to do it.

You can run a celery worker in the background using the detach flag, but I wouldn't recommend this for a production environment. If you want to do this, run the celery worker command first to start the detached process, then start the Django server.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814691/run-a-celery-worker-in-the-background
